# Получить название файла

Tags: c#

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles("G:\\", "*.az", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Далее хочу копировать файлы

```
File.Copy(s1., Path.GetTempPath() + Namer, true);
```

Получаю ошибку

```
указан каталог, а не файл.
```

Как мне получить сам файл?

```
foreach (string s1 in dirs)
        {
            File.Copy(s1, Path.GetTempPath() + Namer, true);
        }
```

Не каких Name или FullName не доступны

Comment: @AK мне нужно и в подпапках искать

Comment: Перед копированием нужно проверять с чем вы работаете: с каталогом или с файлом, если функция возвращает и пути каталогов.

Comment: Владимир, не-а, я тоже сходу подумал, что возвращаются каталоги. Однако там именно имена файлов. Так что обычное Path.GetFileName и Path.GetDirectoryName помогут разбить полный путь на путь и имя файла.

Comment: Как вы планируете обрабатывать ситуацию, когда на диске G есть папки folder1 и folder2, в каждой лежит файл 123.ag -- по идее нужно в целевой папке воссоздавать всю структуру папок, верно?

Comment: @Сергей что хранится в переменной `Namer` ? она, я так понимаю, статична ? ибо не вижу, что в коде где-то менялась.

Answer (score 2):

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles("G:\\", "*.az", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.AsParallel()
.WithDegreeOfParallelism(2)
.ForAll(d => File.Copy(d, Path.GetTempPath()+Path.GetFileName(d),true));
```

.....

```
   string[] Drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
   foreach (string drive in Drives) {

   Directory.EnumerateFiles(drive , "*.az", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
   .AsParallel()
   .WithDegreeOfParallelism(2)
   .ForAll(d => File.Copy(d, Path.GetTempPath() + Path.GetFileName(d), true));
   }
```

С рекурсивным поиском

```
string[] Drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
foreach(string drive in Drives)
Search(drive);

.............
static void Search(string sDir) {
 try {

  Directory.EnumerateFiles(sDir, "*.az")
   .AsParallel()
   .WithDegreeOfParallelism(2)
   .ForAll(d => File.Copy(d, Path.GetTempPath() + Path.GetFileName(d), true));

  foreach(string path in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(sDir))
  Search(path);

 } catch (System.Exception excpt) {
  //Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
 }

}
```

Comment: не пойму куда это добавить?

Comment: @Сергей это вместо всего вашего кода

Comment: файлы просто в temp копируются - а можно ли получить название папки,где лежит сам файл

Comment: так не работает ( Path.GetTempPath() + Namer + "//" + path.Replace("/", "").Replace("\\", "")

Comment: @Сергей было бы неплохо, если бы вы обозначали задачу. Если вы хотите получить директорию, то ф-я  `Path.GetDirectoryName() ` вам поможет, если нужно без названия диска, то можно написать так 
 `Path.GetDirectoryName() .Replace("G:\\","") `

Comment: спасибо - уже сам допер ) - задача собрать все мои плагины формата .az в 1 папку и больше их по папкам не раскидовать )

Comment: @Сергей тогда чем вам мой пример не подошел ? вместо Path.GetTempPath() можете поставить свой путь к папке и все туда будет скидываться. Path.GetTempPath() - я взял с вашего кода, по этому думал, что вы знаете, что она возвращает или вы не поняли мой пример ? я могу объяснить

Comment: я понял - вы мне лучше подскажите как в foreach 1 раз сделать поиск файлов - в foreach определяю диск string[] Drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
            foreach (string s in Drives)
            {
                string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(s, "*.az", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            }

Comment: @Сергей я обновил свой ответ, вам нужно было для всех логических дисков выполнить поиск, я прав ?

Comment: в таком ответе я запутаюсь :D - я вроде уже сделал но получаю ошибки когда проверяется папка по типу C:\Users\Sergey\Documents - как мне дать доступ программно для проверки

Comment: @Сергей на мой вопрос понял ли вы мой пример вы ответили "да", но видимо нет. В моем примере идет сразу поиск и по подпапкам, но стоит получить ошибку (например, доступа нет к директории), как весь поиск рушится. Тут лучше использовать рекурсивный поиск и там ловить исключения

Comment: @Сергей добавил пример с рекурсивным поиском

Comment: теперь а как выбрать по размеру?Плагины весят от 3 до 100 кб максимум - куда Length прописать можно?

Comment: @Сергей 1 тема = 1 вопрос, старайтесь этого придерживаться, что бы не устраивать большие дискуссии в комментариях, а так - `.Where(d => new FileInfo(d).Length > 10)` перед распараллеливанием поставьте. Учтите, что размер в байтах

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles("G:\\", "*.az", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

string newPath = "C:\\";

foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
{
    //string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
    string name = Path.GetFileName(fileName);

    //Console.WriteLine(path);
    //Console.WriteLine(name);

    var sourceName = fileName;
    var destName = Path.Combine(newPath, name);
    File.Copy(sourceName, destName);
}
```

PS Код упрощённый, чисто для демонстрации Path.GetFileName и Path.Combine.

Я тут подумал: на самом деле если в папке есть две подпапки 1 и 2 и в каждой лежит 123.ag то они запишутся в одно и то же место, один пропадёт. По-хорошему нужно воссоздавать структуру каталогов.

Comment: @A K - а можно после копирования сразу его переименовать?

Comment: @Сергей Тут есть варианты. Если вы изначально хотите копировать с новыми рандомными/гуидообразными именами, то тут шансы на то, что такой файл уже будет ничтожны. А если вам нужны исходные имена и лишь в случае если они совпадают то переименовывать... То вариантов два: либо заранее проверить имя файла, либо отлавливать IOException -- [согласно MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx) это как раз ситуация "файл уже существует". Я бы проверял существование файла, это надёжнее (см. описание эксепшена, там более одного варианта).

Comment: И вообще: лучше не копировать, а потом переименовывать -- а сразу подбирать имя, которого не будет. Я же вам разобрал на отдельные переменные и можно собрать их обратно в любом нужном порядке.

Comment: @A K я сделал вроде - папки создаются - только не пойму как копировать именно по такому пути - который есть например : есть .az G:\boot\Нужное\Plugin.az- я воссоздал папки по пути temp - G - папки - вот как копировать файл в ту папку,в которой он был на G

Comment: @Сергей Нажимаете на своём вопросе кнопку редактировать, вписываете свой новый код в конец вопроса - и тогда попробую ответить. Пока я не могу понять, что и как вы воссоздаёте и что и как вы копируете -- и отвечать вслепую не хочу.